# In CakePHP, how to get the client file name from an array of images?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I am trying to upload images into an array. I want the array to store the name of the image. However, I get an error every time I use the `getClientFilename()` method to grab the name of the image. The error I get is:

> Call to a member function getClientFilename() on array

and this error is because the `$otherName` variable uses the `getClientFilename()` method. How do you get the client file name from an array of images? If you look at the image example, I want to grab the clientfilename value of `vashion.jpg`.

**SubmissionsController.php**

```
if(!is_dir(WWW_ROOT.'otherImg'.DS.$folder)) {
    mkdir(WWW_ROOT.'otherImg'.DS.$folder, 0775);
}
foreach($this->request->getData('data') as $otherImage) {
    debug($otherImage);
    $otherName = $otherImage->getClientFilename();
    //Add to data to save
    $imgData = array(
        "original_pathname" => $otherImage,
        "submission_id" => $submission->id
    );

    $this->Submission->Image->create();
    $this->Submission->Image->save($imgData);
                    
    if(!$this->Submission->Image->save($imgData)) {
        $this->Flash->error(__('The other images could not be uploaded.'));
    }
}
```

**add.php**

```
<table id="uploads_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Upload Other Images (max of 25)<input type="hidden" name="data[Image][num_images]" id="num_images" value="1" /></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot></tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="file" name="data[Image][file][]" id="ImageFile1" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="add_image" name="add_image" value="Add Another Image" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This image shows the debug output of the foreach loop. I am trying to return the clientfilename.

[image]

Comment: Check this documentation https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/request-response.html#file-uploads

Also you can see this tutorial 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qgt1ALhWMeA

Comment: Your debug output confirms that what you have in `$otherImage` is indeed an array, as your error message has told you. The object in question is at `$otherImage->file`.

Comment: @SatuSultana, I have watched that YouTube video before. It was very helpful when I needed to upload a single image. However, it doesn't go over uploading an array of images. I was also looking at the documentation website that you linked, but I am still stuck. I could use some examples or a better explanation than what is on the documentation. Thanks.

Comment: @GreySchmidt, debug($otherImage->file[0]->getClientFilename()); gives me a notice that says 'Trying to get property 'file' of non-object'. Any ideas on how to access the clientfilename? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution to my problem with this code:

```
foreach($this->request->getData('data') as $otherImage) {
  for($key = 0; $key < $otherImage['num_images']; $key++) {
     $otherName = $otherImage['file'][$key]->getClientFilename(); //Get file original name
     //Add to data to save
     $imgData = array(
        "original_pathname" => $folder.'/'.$otherName,
        "submission_id" => $submission->id
      );

      if($otherName) {
       $otherImage['file'][$key]->moveTo(WWW_ROOT.'otherImg'.DS.$folder.DS.$otherName); // move files to destination folder
      }
   }
}
```

This returns `vashion.jpg`.